# Batch File only works right when user inputs yes to both questions.. otherwise it crashes

Tags: batch-file, input, crash

I asked a question here earlier today and got that fixed, but now I have another problem.. My batch file is supposed to take the user input of a directory and then save all of the names of the files within that directory to a user specified name text file. It also has the option to allow for you to include or not include subdirectories and Hidden/System files. My problem is that it only works right when the user decides to include both Hidden/System files and subdirectories, otherwise, it crashes.. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
:start
set /P DIRECTORY=Type Directory to Search: 
if not exist %DIRECTORY% goto :firstlogin
set /P FILENAME=Type the name for your output file:


:choice
set /P c=Include Sub-Directories?[y/n]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :somewhere
if /I "%c%" EQU "y" goto :somewhere
if /I "%c%" EQU "Yes" goto :somewhere
if /I "%c%" EQU "yes" goto :somewhere
if /I "%c%" EQU "YES" goto :somewhere
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :somewhere_else
if /I "%c%" EQU "n" goto :somewhere_else
if /I "%c%" EQU "No" goto :somewhere_else
if /I "%c%" EQU "no" goto :somewhere_else
if /I "%c%" EQU "NO" goto :somewhere_else
goto :choice


:somewhere
set /P d=Include Hidden and System Files?[y/n]?
if /I "%d%" EQU "Y" goto :d1
if /I "%d%" EQU "y" goto :d1
if /I "%d%" EQU "Yes" goto :d1
if /I "%d%  EQU "yes" goto :d1
if /I "%d%" EQU "YES" goto :d1
if /I "%d%" EQU "N" goto :d2
if /I "%d%" EQU "n" goto :d2
if /I "%d%" EQU "No" goto :d2
if /I "%d%" EQU "no" goto :d2
if /I "%d%" EQU "NO" goto :d2
goto :somewhere

:d1
echo The Program Will Exit When Operations are Completed....
Pause
echo Working Please Wait... 
Pause
dir /a /s /b /o  "%DIRECTORY%" > C:\Users\Zack\Desktop\%FILENAME%.txt
exit


:d2
echo The Program Will Exit When Operations are Completed....
Pause
echo Working Please Wait... 
Pause
dir /s /b /o  "%DIRECTORY%" > C:\Users\Zack\Desktop\%FILENAME%.txt
exit



:somewhere_else
set /P e=Include Hidden and System Files?[y/n]?
if /I "%e%" EQU "Y" goto :e1
if /I "%e%" EQU "y" goto :e1
if /I "%e%" EQU "Yes" goto :e1
if /I "%e%" EQU "yes" goto :e1
if /I "%e%" EQU "YES" goto :e1
if /I "%e%" EQU "N" goto :e2
if /I "%e%" EQU "n" goto :e2
if /I "%e%" EQU "No" goto :e2
if /I "%e%" EQU "no" goto :e2
if /I "%e%" EQU "NO" goto :e2
goto :somewhere_else


e1:
echo The Program Will Exit When Operations are Completed....
Pause
echo Working Please Wait... 
Pause
dir /a /b /o  "%DIRECTORY%" > C:\Users\Zack\Desktop\%FILENAME%.txt
exit


e2:
echo The Program Will Exit When Operations are Completed....
Pause
echo Working Please Wait... 
Pause
dir /b /o "%DIRECTORY%" > C:\Users\Zack\Desktop\%FILENAME%.txt
exit


:firstlogin
echo Directory does not exist!
Pause
goto :start


:done
SET stg=
SET /P stg=Start again?[y/n]? 
cls
IF %stg% == Y goto :START
IF %stg% == y goto :START
IF %stg% == yes goto :START
IF %stg% == Yes goto :START
IF %stg% == YES goto :START
```

Comment: 'otherwise, it crashes.. ' how?

Comment: what does the batch do when it crashes?  Have you followed the flow by `REM`'ing the `@echo off` command?

Comment: It just closes without doing anything, and no I haven't followed the flow yet; I'll try that now. EDIT: Following the flow didn't help, it appeared to be running perfectly, everything was going where it should, but then it crashed..

Comment: what was the last command that was executed?

Comment: I entered "n" when this line: 'set /P e=Include Hidden and System Files?[y/n]?' asked for it, it checked through all of the variables below really quick, got through all of them, then crashed.

Comment: Carlos's answer solved my problem except for one thing, when I enter y then n (so it should go to :d2) it crashes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple typo:

```
e1: 
echo The Program Will Exit When Operations are Completed....
```

should be:

```
:e1
echo The Program Will Exit When Operations are Completed....
```

Same for `e2:`, should be `:e2`.

Pay attention to the error messages...

**Edit:**

About your comment, check:

```
:somewhere 
set /P d=Include Hidden and System Files?[y/n]? 
if /I "%d%" EQU "Y" goto :d1 
if /I "%d%" EQU "y" goto :d1 
if /I "%d%" EQU "Yes" goto :d1 
if /I "%d%  EQU "yes" goto :d1
```

The last line is missing a `"` after `"%d`.

It's very easy to debug things like this. Just change `echo off` to `echo on` at the beginning and you'll see which was the last executed line and the error message.

Comment: EDIT: Well that solved one of the problems, now if I enter n for both it works, but entering y then n, still makes it crash.. (When it should go to :d2)